# What would cause the inner contents of a `with` statement to not execute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, with-statement, silent

When I run the following code, no error messages are printed, and it seems to fail silently. I expected the string `"BLAH"` to be printed to the console.

```python
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import io # the initialism `io` represents `INPUT OUTPUT LIBRARY`

def run_solver():
    print("solver is running")

with io.StringIO() as fake_std_out:
    with redirect_stdout(fake_std_out):
        print("BLAH") # THIS IS NEVER PRINTED
        run_solver()
        data = fake_std_out.getvalue()
        print(data)
print("THE END")
```

The output I expect is:

```
BLAH
solver is running
THE END
```

Instead, we have:

```
THE END
```

## Edits

1. I realize now that I wanted to *copy* standard output, not re-direct it.
2. Using `print` to print the contents of the string stream won't work because the destination of the print function is now the string stream instead of the system console. After calling `getvalue()` it makes no sense to attempt to use print statements anymore.

Comment: It's doing exactly what you asked. stdout is being redirected to fake_std_out. What did you think redirect_stdout was going to do?

Comment: `print` writes to standard output (whatever that might be), not directly to the console.

Comment: Your question is really asking "how can I print to real standard out while standard out is redirected elsewhere?" And the answer to that is, `print("BLAH", file=sys.__stdout__)`

Answer (score 2):

The code is working fine. `print` writes to standard output, not the console directly. You can check for the values written to `fake_std_out` yourself following the inner `with` statement.

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import io

def run_solver():
    print("solver is running")

with io.StringIO() as fake_std_out:
    with redirect_stdout(fake_std_out):
        print("BLAH")
        run_solver()

    assert fake_std_out.getvalue() == 'BLAH\nsolver is running\n'

print("THE END")
```